# Matching inputed data to MySQL stored data. Token based auth style

Tags: php, authentication, token

I am trying to use token based authentication. Essentially I have come to the conclusion that I must retrieve the hashed data from the server in order to match the data inputed which then gets sent back to the server still hashed and a token gets signed and sent back to the user.

I have used a similar code to register the user to the database. So I figure if I can essentially reverse it, it would do the same thing but verify the input instead of making a new record.

If I am off the beaten path please let me know.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password = hash("sha256", $password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `registration-user` WHERE ( '$name', '$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($result){
        $smsg = "User Logged In Successfully.";
    }else{
        $fmsg = "User Login Failed";
    }
}
```

I have searched for hours on this topic only to find much much more complicated not very straightforward ways of doing this. Hoping I can simplify it. Obviously adding more robust security to the code. All I am looking for right now is functionality that works similar to Token Based Authentication.

All help is greatly appreciated in documenting a simplified way of validating hashed(SHA256) server data.

T registration code which works perfectly fine. It takes the input and places it in the database while applying the sha256 hash to the $password variable. Here is the only difference.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `registration-user` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$email', '$password')";
```

VS

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `registration-user` WHERE ( '$name', '$password')";
```

Comment: maybe do like an md5 hash the name or password and make that the auth token? then, you would be able to just add a column in MySQL that would allow you to lookup based on it? Sorry if i didn't make sense.. I am tired.

Comment: @McStuffins MD5 isn't nearly as secure as sha256. The data being stored in the end would be very sensitive data and I cannot risk using a hash that has many documented attacks.

Comment: I was talking about just a token... I you can use any way that you would like to generate the token, but in the end you will need to store the token with the user in a database.

Comment: maybe give me a design pattern to follow? I cannot really imagine it. What are you worried about?

Comment: @McStuffins I get it now. I am just trying to think if that method would be secure. From what it sounds like, were essentially just hashing the data the same both ways which would in terms create the same effect when matching the data.

Comment: Is this for a website? if it is, then I would send the post in an ajax call with some kind of token in the header or in the body. I with sensitive information, I highly recommend you use a token system between the server and the client because that removed the possibility that it is coming from a man in the middle. You would of course need to add extra security measures, but I am sure that it is worth it.

Comment: @McStuffins well first of all md5 is deprecated many years ago as not being sufficient security. sha256 is just more complicated especially with the salt.

By using sha256 hashing on registration for the storage, I should only have to hash it once more in order to verify that what the user is inputting is correct. 

once the data is matched I can then create the token which gets signed by the server before getting sent back to the user.

Comment: My apologies yes this is for a php based website.

Comment: well, I then highly recommend using the doing what I said earlier.